# How to pick out every nth tick label to show on the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have a list of dates that i specifically selected for the x-axis.

```
dates = data.index[-len(test):]
```

When I plot the graph using `ax1.set_xticklabels([d.date() for d in dates])`, it only shows 7 ticks and instead of having them be evenly spread out, such that the first tick is the first one in the list, and the last tick in the last, it just picks the first 7.

Is there any way to make the plot pick out tick labels depending on how many tick marks it decides to use automatically? Or do I have to go in and manually pick out dates and manually assign the number of ticks in the plot so that their quantities match?

Comment: You should never need to set ticks manually (but you can of course). What's the reason to use `set_ticklabels` in the first place?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest There are several sets of timeseries data that get converted into np.arrays. I'm not sure how else to label the x-axis other than explicitly pull out dates from the dataset and use that as tick labels.

Comment: Matplotlib should automatically label the axes depending on the data that is plotted - as said, there should usually not be any need to do that manually. To find out what kind of unusual case you face here it would be helpful to see a [mcve] of the issue and a description of what the axes look like and in how far that is undesired.